# Zend and Jquery (Ajax Post)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework, post

I'm using zend framework, i would like to get POST data using Jquery ajax post on a  to save without refreshing the page.

```
//submit.js

$(function() {

    $('#buttonSaveDetails').click(function (){
        var details = $('textarea#details').val();
        var id = $('#task_id').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost/myproject/public/module/save',
            async: false,
            data: 'id=' + id + '&details=' + details,
            success: function(responseText) {
                //alert(responseText)
                console.log(responseText);
            }

        });
    });
});
```

On my controller, I just don't know how to retrieve the POST data from ajax.

```
public function saveAction() 
{

    $data = $this->_request->getPost();
    echo $id = $data['id'];
    echo $details = $data['details'];
    //this wont work;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Set `$.ajax`'s `dataType` option to 'json', and modify the success callback to read from the received JSON:

```
$('#buttonSaveDetails').click(function (){
    var details = $('textarea#details').val();
    var id = $('#task_id').val();
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'http://localhost/myproject/public/module/save',
            async: false,

            // you can use an object here
            data: { id: id, details: details },
            success: function(json) {
                console.log(json.id + ' ' + json.details);
            }
    });

    // you might need to do this, to prevent anchors from following
    // or form controls from submitting
    return false;
});
```

And from your controller, send the data like this:

```
$data = $this->_request->getPost();
echo Zend_Json::encode(array('id' => $data['id'], 'details' => $data['details']));
```

As a closing point, make sure that automatic view rendering has been disabled, so the only output going back to the client is the JSON object.

Comment: @Zend_Newbie_Dev - Any time :)

Comment: Some simplifications to [karim79](http://stackoverflow.com/users/70393/karim79)'s [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559808/zend-and-jquery-ajax-post/4559825#4559825): 1. `$.ajax`'s `url` can also be relative (recommended within the same domain), 2. `$.ajax`'s `data` can also be generated using `$("#formId").serialize()` (does URL encoding automatically)

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way for getting this is:

```
$details=$this->getRequest()->getPost('details');

$id= $this->getRequest()->getPost('id');
```

Hope this will work for you.